# HTML not loading in .php file

Tags: php, html

[UPDATED]

I have two files on my web server: **test.php and test.html**

Both **test.php** and **test.html** contain the same code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.html** prints out 'Hello' as expected but **test.php** is returning a blank page.
What could be the problem

Contents of .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^http://www.alcratech.com/index.html$ https://www.alcratech.com/index.html [R=301,L]
```

Contents of

Comment: Can you share the code with us?

Comment: *"You can click here to see the error"* - Err... no. Post your code and the error in your question. I for one, will not "fetch", but my dog will.

Comment: Check your error log

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The working HTML file is at www.alcratech.com/test.html

Comment: No ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ post your "code". and the error. Your question will render useless for future readers too and once you "figure it out".

Comment: The code is 500 lines long. I dont know where the error is so I can't a snippet

Comment: check your logs as stated already. Or add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: You can also make up a pastebin file http://pastebin.com/ and post the link for it in your question. Just make sure you don't set it to expire.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I pasted the link to *"You can see the error at..."*  into Firefox ... and it results in an HTTP 500 ... so it's quite likely this has absolutely nothing to do with PHP (itself) ... *smells* like a server misconfiguration to me.

Comment: I have updated the question and corrected the errors

Comment: check your configuration. Your PHP interpreter is failing you somewhere. If that is your own server rather than from a hosted service, then something went haywire. There's nothing else I can think of at this point. Might be related to an `.htaccess` file too, hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your PHP is misconfigured, and invoking it results in a server error. Possible reasons might be for example loading a non existing extension in your php.ini file. You need to check your apache error log to check this. If you are using PHP-FPM check if it is started and running, also check the php-fpm error log.